# Changing `ylim` on `cartopy` with different `central_longitude`

Tags: python, matplotlib, gis, cartopy

I want to create a map on Mercator projection from -60S to 60N but with -160W as the central longitude.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,
        projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=0)
)
ax.set_extent([-180,180,-60,60])
ax.coastlines(resolution='110m')
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
```

Returns the expected result for `central_longitude=0`

[image]

But if `central_longitude=-60`

It returns

[image]

My questions are:

1. Why `cartopy` is behaving like this?
2. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify correct values in the relevant option arguments. The default values are not always valid.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

noproj = ccrs.PlateCarree()  #central_longitude=0
myproj = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=-60)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,
        projection = myproj
)

# *** Dont use 180 but 179.95 to avoid mysterious error
# longitudes -180 and +180 are sometimes interpreted as the same location
# Also specify `crs` correctly
ax.set_extent([-179.95, 179.95, -60, 60], crs=noproj)
# In the more recent versions of Cartopy, you can use [-180,180,-60,60] 
ax.coastlines(resolution='110m')
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True)

plt.show()
```

[image: output1]

**Edit**

Note that the labels for 60 degrees N and S are missing. To get them printed on the map you need this

```
ax.set_extent([-179.95, 179.95, -60.01, 60.01], crs=noproj)
```

as a replacement for the relevant line of code.

Comment: That makes sense. When we use `central_longitude=0`, we probably don't need to use the projection because `matplotlib` coordinates are the same as `cartopy`'s. Right?
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @iurysimoes-sousa `cartopy` is needed to enable geospatial features.

Comment: Yes, what I mean is that for `central_longitude=0`, there is a coincidence between `matplotlib` axis coordinates and `cartopy`, which led to the expected behavior even though I didn't pass the transform function. I am just trying to understand what happened.